# SwiftUI MultiDatePicker selection breaks on non-empty initial selection

Tags: swiftui, datepicker

I need an initial selection for `MultiDatePicker`. I tried assigning it in `init` as you can see below and in `onAppear`. In both cases deselecting the initial selection does not work, it always stays in `dates`. How to fix this?

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var dates: Set<DateComponents>
    
    init() {
        let now = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: .now)
        _dates = State(initialValue: [now])
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            MultiDatePicker("", selection: $dates)
                .onChange(of: dates) {_ in
                    print("Selection changed")
                }
            Text(datesStr)
        }.padding()
    }
    
    var datesStr: String {
        dates
            .map{ Calendar.current.date(from: $0)!.formatted(date: .numeric, time: .omitted) }
            .joined(separator: "\n")
    }
}
```

Same problem with this one-liner by the way (which does not meet my needs because it is not dynamic):

```swift
@State private var dates: Set<DateComponents> = [Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: .now)]
```

Tested in Xcode 14.0.1 and 14.1 beta 3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply use `[.calendar, .era, .year, .month, .day]` instead of `[.year, .month, .day]`. That is the `DateComponents` format `MultiDatePicker` expects.

I just found this solution after wondering why the same `DateComponents` can appear twice in the `Set` (which as you know only allows unique elements). Well, they were not exactly the same.